# How to make a transition of opacity from 0 to 1 with Compass?

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, opacity, compass-sass

I'm trying to build up a fade style using CSS3 (and SASS/Compass to be readable)

I would like to make the elements turn from full transparency to full opacity.
I tried something like that:

```
@import "compass/css3/transition";
@import "compass/css3/opacity";

.fade{
    @include transparent;
    @include transition(opacity(1), 2s ease-out);
}
```

With that try, there's no transition effect, and the element remains transparent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Compass documentation](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/transition/) shows, you do have to specify the intended pseudo-element. Otherwise, how will the browser know if the transition is supposed to occur on :hover or some other action.

Also, don't include the `(1)` argument in the opacity call:

```
.fade{
  @include transparent;
  @include transition(opacity, 2s ease-out);
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/jHtGF?editors=010).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which matches my question the way I formulated it. However, your answer just made me realize I should use Animation instead.  I'd like to reproduce a Fade In onload effect.

Answer (score -1):

I finally used a SCSS version of this SASS mixin: http://thecssguru.freeiz.com/animate/